# Web2Py CSS style in IMG()

Tags: python, html, css, web2py

I'm trying to get the basic syntax for setting a CSS `<style>` using a call to `{{=IMG()}}` in Web2Py. I've tried the following:

```
 <style>img.bottom { vertical-align: text-bottom; } </style>
 <body>
     {{=IMG(_src=URL('static',args='images/golem.jpg', _style='img.bottom'),_alt="golem"}}
 </body>
```

fail

```
 <body>
     {{=IMG(_src=URL('static',args='images/golem.jpg', styles={'CODE':'vertical-align: text-bottom;'}), _alt="golem")}}
 <body>
```

also fail

```
 <style>img.bottom { vertical-align: text-bottom; } </style>
 <body>
      {{=IMG(_src=URL('static',args='images/golem.jpg'), _style='bottom',_alt="golem"}}
 </body>
```

also fail

```
 <style>img.bottom { vertical-align: text-bottom; } </style>
 <body>
      {{=IMG(_src=URL('static',args='images/golem.jpg'), _class='bottom',_alt="golem"}}
 </body>
```

also fail

I feel like I must be close but I can't find an argument for style to `IMG()` in the docs and I can't seem to override the (non)style that's present.

[Just in case anyone wants to see the Web2Py docs where the answer is not](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#IMG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
{{=IMG(_src=URL('static', 'images', args='golem.jpg'), _alt='golem',
       _style='vertical-align: text-bottom')}}
```

or:

```
<style>img.bottom {vertical-align: text-bottom;}</style>
{{=IMG(_src=URL('static', 'images', args='golem.jpg'), _alt='golem',
       _class='bottom')}}
```

As noted [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#HTML-helpers) in the documentation:

> Named arguments that start with an underscore are interpreted as HTML tag attributes (without the underscore).

Although the book doesn't specifically show an example of using the "_style" or "_class" arguments with `IMG`, there are numerous examples of the "_class" argument as well as other HTML attributes being used with other HTML helpers.

Comment: You're (as usual) right. I know I tried this one. I must have had a typo.

Comment: Hi.Is there an option to randomly select an image from several images?

Comment: If you're asking whether the `IMG()` helper includes such an option, no (seems like a rare use case for a simple HTML helper), but it's just Python code, so should be trivial to write your own code to select a random image.

Comment: Something close to: <img src="//www.yoursite.com/random_i echo(mt_rand(1,3)); ?> .jpg">

Comment: Something close to: <img src="//www.yoursite.com/random_i echo(mt_rand(1,3)); ?> .jpg">

Answer (score 0):

While this *does* work, I don't like it. It's ugly and I'm not accepting it as an answer. Just wanted to give a workaround in case someone else finds this (unanswered) next year.

```
 <style> img.bottom { vertical-align: text-bottom; } </style>
 <body>
     <img src={{=URL('static','images',args='golem.jpg')}} alt="golem"class=bottom>
 </body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to randomly select an image from the static/images folder?

Comment: @wakamdr You'd either have to maintain a hardcoded list/dictionary in the javascript or do it server side by querying the directory in python / php / whatever your page runs on. That could make a good question all by itself (if it isn't already answered. I didn't search.)